# How to append string in local resource txt file for iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, append

I have been trying to append strings to a local resource file but I am having trouble finding a solution. I am trying to create a log file for all the function call in my application so if it crashes I can see which function it stopped on.

I have created a log.rtf file, but am not able to write in this file. Can someone please help me append a string to this file without having to overwrite the entire thing?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have use following code for the above problem.

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *logPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"log.rtf"]];
NSFileHandle *fileHandler = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:logPath];
[fileHandler seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandler writeData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fileHandler closeFile];
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you can do this..

```
+ (void)WriteLogWithString:(NSString *)log
{

        if(log != nil){

            NSString *locationFilePath = [self getLogFilePath];//access the path of file

            FILE *fp = fopen([locationFilePath UTF8String], "a");

            fprintf(fp,"%s\n", [log UTF8String]);

            fclose(fp);
        }

}
```

Comment: thanks Sachin, but this will add to starting of your file, not at end of file.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)log:(NSString *)message {
    NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/log.txt", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]]];
    if (!string) string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [string appendFormat:@"%@\r\n", message];
    [string writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/log.txt", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
```

Comment: @ Tim, 'writeToFile:atomically:' is deprecated from XCode 4.1

Comment: What if size of the file is above 10k. Then mutable string cannot hold this much of data, then it will cause app crash. Please try this and let me know. Take a txt doc. With 10k size and try to append one line using this code.