# How to write to a text file without overwriting the contents of the file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to append string in local resource txt file for iOS sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041237/how-to-append-string-in-local-resource-txt-file-for-ios-sdk)

My code goes like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];

docFile_V1 = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:LOG_FILE_V1];
if ([file fileExistsAtPath: docFile_V1] == YES)
{     
    if(![formatedlogStr writeToFile:docFile_V1  atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error userInfo]);
    }
}
```

This is my code for writing into the file, but unfortunately it overwrites all the previous contents of the file. I want to write a string without overwriting the previous one.

Can anybody suggest the best way to write or append to the file by example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should read the contents of the file in a NSMutableArray, then append your data to your array, and write it to the file again.